# Intercept Build Request in Eclipse - Before Compilation

Tags: eclipse, build-process

I was wondering in Eclipse if it's possible to intercept when a user hits save or 'ctrl + s' via some sort of listener. What I want to do is determine when a file in a project changes and receive this notification before the file is actually compiled, so that I can update a property in the class. Afterwards, I would like the file to be compiled as per normal. Is this at all possible? Similar to the idea of a database trigger I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant`. From the description:

> This extension point allows clients to participate in the compilation process by receiving notifications at various stages of build and reconcile, via a org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationParticipant.

Comment: Have you got an example of how to build one of these? I've never touched anything like this before and don't know where to start with this.

Comment: @Joeblackdev I'll check tomorrow. Stay tuned.